# How to set distance between 2 objects?

Tags: modeling

Is there any add-ons where I can adjust the distance between 2 objects accurately? I am not asking about measurement but location objects w.r.t to each other.
For ex:
[image: Can this be easily adjusted in blender?]

Comment: Do you mean closest points on surfaces, or object origins?

Comment: Object Origins will do. I will be working with hard surface modeling so it will be all boolean.

Comment: Could you provide more details? At first though, no addon is needed for that.

Comment: I am from CAD background. So, trying to get my head around placing things accurately. I have edited my questions with an image so you will know what I mean. If blender can work with accuracy, my life will be easier ton times!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proceed in two steps: rotate the object the angle you want, then move it along its axis.

For a better visualization, you can activate "show axis", here we want to move the monkey from the cube:

[image]

From that rotate the angle you want: <kbd>R</kbd> and use the mouse and eventually set the value manually in the operator panl.

Then move along the axis <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>XX</kbd> (twice) to move along local axis, and again you can also set the value manually.

[image]

To keep them in the same configuration when moving, select one then shift select the second and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: This worked well :) Can you help me by elaborating the last line? I mean same configuration in the sense?

Comment: I meant, stay at the same relative positions/angles. You can move the parent and the child will follow.

Comment: Ok. Got it (y) Thank you again :)

Answer (score 6):

You can just use a Limit Distance constraint for that. Simply add the constraint in the Constraints properties and set the target to your other object. Set Distance to the distance you require and Clamp Region to 'On Surface'. This will constrain your object to remain on the surface of a sphere projected around the target object.

[image: limit distance constraint]

Comment: Ok. I will try this method. I used to use grid snapping and place them step by step. I found it cumbersome. But any other thing which can help on the fly? I mean as soon as I place and pick up centers of 2 object then I can start dimensioning?